# Is it possible to force the cleaner to compact a partition log for partitions with very low traffic?

Tags: apache-kafka

**Is it possible to force the cleaner to compact a partition log for partitions with very low traffic?**

For a topic with `retention.policy` set to `"compact, delete"` it is understood that compaction (and for null records - deletion) takes place when a cleaner thread decides to clean a log. This decision is based on a few things. Relevant to this question is the segment roll functionality; unless a new segment is created compaction won't run.

Segment roll may be configured via `segment.ms` and `segment.bytes`.

Now, for the question. Since active segments won't be cleaned and a new segment doesn't become active until a record has been written to it, is it possible to force the cleaner to compact a partition log for topics that no longer receive any write-traffic?

Example log:

```
$ kcat -b kafka:9092 -t foo -C -K:
1:hello
2:world
1:
```

Regardless of configuration, unless a records is written after `1:null` compaction does not run. However:

```
$ echo "3:compact" | kcat -b kafka:9092 -t foo -P -K:
# `segment.ms` time passes
$ kcat -b kafka:9092 -t foo -C -K:
2:world
1:
3:compact
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've investigated further over at the Confluent Community and got it verified that a segment rolls when the timestamp of a written record differs more than segment.ms from the first record in the currently active segment.

In other words, a segment never rolls unless a record is written. So, the answer to the question is "no, it is not possible".

Comment: If the topic is "compact" I believe the max.compaction.lag.ms should force compaction even with no writes to the log: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms  - it looks like it just makes it eligible though, ignoring min.compact.ratio and a write still is required to roll the log

Answer (score 0):

If log.cleaner.backoff.ms has the default value (15000) the cleanup thread(s) should run every 15 seconds. Of course if there is nothing to cleanup nothing is done. The tombstone messages (null messages) are included in the cleanup process. If compact and delete policies are both enabled, the delete policy should follow the log.retention.* parameters. Of course no active segment can be deleted. Anyway pay attention, because the cleanup thread(s) work on the full partition segment by segment, and when cleanup is completed for one segment the same one is replaced by the cleaned one. If the cleanup thread(s) does not have enough memory to cleanup a segment it is skipped, but you should see an error on kafka log. If traffic is low you should perhaps tune your segment closure policy using log.segment.bytes and log.segment.ms.

Comment: My guess is that for a new segment to become active, a record has to be written to it. So, in my first example log, after `1:null` is written and enough time has passed so that `log.segment.ms` causes a new segment roll, the cleaner still  won't consider the previous segment for cleanup until a record is written to the new segment.

Comment: When you use the compact retention policy you want to keep in kafka the latest message for a single key, so the null value for key 1 is regarded as tombstone message for key 1. This means that after a configurable time (delete.retention.ms) the message is deleted from the topic. Remember that compaction and deletion never occur on active segments, only on inactive ones.

Comment: Hi, again, the issue relates to topics with low or non-existent write-traffic. Since a new segment doesn't appear to become active until at least one record is written to it, the question is if it is possible to trigger compaction in any other manner.

Comment: As I wrote, I don't think so.

Comment: I suffered the same. The problem can be described as "a segment already marked for rolling, and therefore, qualifying for compaction, can never be effectively closed until a new record is produced so the new segment file is filled". IMO, Kafka should create an empty log file with expected base offset and leave it empty until new message arrives

Comment: Otherwise, things like max.compaction.lag.ms defy its reliability and thus their purpose